# Remote Desktop 7 XP -> Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I am running Windows 7 at my office and Windows XP at home.  I have seen the new Remote Desktop and want to use (I have three monitors at office and three at home)

In the specs I saw where in order to use the multimon features you must connect to a Windows 7 client (I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit in my office)  When I connect to it (from XP running RDP 7) I can't get all my monitors to come up, just one

Is there something I am doing wrong?  Both are running the same version of RDP

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

For native multi-monitor support, the target machine has to be running Windows 7 Ultimate - this feature is NOT supported in Professional.  I am unsure if, in that scenario, it'll work from XP (you also need to be using the newest version of RDP obviously) but I can guarantee you that Ultimate is required for proper support.

You may be able to use the old-fashioned 'span' mode but I'm not certain about this as I haven't tried under 7.

Comment: I did not know that RDP differed between Professional and Ultimate, but I'll add that it multi monitor support must be in Enterprise as well.

Comment: @paradroid - I am unsure, but I'd assume Enterprise behaves like Ultimate in this situation, of course.  Basically, if the target machine is Ultimate, you can use ALL the local monitors.  If it's not, you only get one.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to tick the "Use all my monitors for the remote session" under Display-tab when connecting.

See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125234108/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx)